# Nested Json Serialise with Custom Class

Tags: flutter, dart, jsonserializer

I have a JSON data from the server from which I want to add specific JSON data to another class but maintaining its instance in the parent class

Json data from server:
{
"id:"1,
"name":"mike",
"classname:"STD-4"
}

```
@JsonSerialize
class Student{

  @JsonKey(name:"id")
  int id;
  StudentInfo studentInfo;

}

@JsonSerialize
class StudentInfo{

  @JsonKey(name:"name")
    String name;
  @JsonKey(name:"classname")
    String classname;

}
```

Is this possible with JsonSerialize lib in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Student{

  @JsonKey(name:"id")
  int id;
  StudentInfo studentInfo;

}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class StudentInfo{

  @JsonKey(name:"name")
    String name;
  @JsonKey(name:"classname")
    String classname;

}
```

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work fine. I assume you are using this package - https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable?

There is also a parameter called `explicitToJson`, read more about it at https://pub.dev/documentation/json_serializable/latest/type_helper/ClassConfig/explicitToJson.html.